# Enabling SNI with appcmd.exe

Tags: ssl, iis-8.5

We currently use appcmd.exe to create IIS websites on the fly with the necessary http/https bindings, e.g.

```
appcmd add site /name:www.example.com /bindings:"http://www.example.com:80","https://www.example.com:443" /physicalPath:"c:\sites\www.example.com"
```

Is there a way to tell the https binding to use SNI?

We're using IIS8.5 / Windows 2012 R2

Comment: [http://serverfault.com/questions/688178/command-line-to-set-up-sni-on-iis-for-windows-2012](http://serverfault.com/questions/688178/command-line-to-set-up-sni-on-iis-for-windows-2012) ?

Comment: We want to achieve via appcmd, not possible?

Comment: [https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/sites/site/bindings/binding#005](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/sites/site/bindings/binding#005) SSL Flag is `1`. Try `appcmd add site /name:www.example.com /bindings:"http://www.example.com:80","https://www.example.com:443"  /sslFlags:1 /physicalPath:"c:\sites\www.example.com`

Comment: No luck, get... Unknown attribute "sslFlags"

Answer (score 0):

I have yet to be able to determine the necessary delimiter to use when specifying the bindings attribute values with the `add site` `appcmd`, however I have accomplished this with the `set site` `appcmd` as follows:

```
appcmd set site /site.name:www.example.com /+bindings.[protocol='https',bindingInformation='*:443:www.example.com',sslFlags='1']
```

Seems like there should be a way to specify the `sslFlags` with the `add site` command as well, but I haven't figured it out yet.

Comment: Unfortunately, this seems to create a binding with SNI enabled but no certificate selected. If I open IIS and open the binding information dialog, I have to select a certificate (despite exactly one exists that matches the created site domain).